# Kotlin having trouble scanning two different QR code and store value

Tags: android, kotlin

> Using google mobile version to scan QR code, having two steps to scan two QR code:
>
> Step 1: Click button1 to get first QR code's information then show it on Textview1 in MainActivity.
>
> Step 2: Click button2 to get second QR code's information then show it on Textview2 in MainActivity.
>
> My problem is that I can only pass QR code's value to my MainActivity separately, it means after I get first QR code and then click button2 to scan the second one , i will lose my first value in my textview1.

My MainActivity get Values from two Qrcode Activties:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btn_2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, FirstQrcodeActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        btn_1.setOnClickListener {
            val box_intent = Intent(this, SecondQrcodeActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(box_intent)
        }

    }
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val First_qrcode= intent?.getStringExtra("First_Qrcode")
        val Second_qrcode= intent?.getStringExtra("Second_Qrcode")
        if(First_qrcode!=null){
            text_view1.text = First_qrcode
        }
        if(Second_qrcode!=null){
            text_view2.text= Second_qrcode
        }
    
    }
```

Main code in First QRcode Activity , passing values to MainActivity:

```
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        svBarcode = findViewById(R.id.sv_Firstbarcode)
        detector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS).build()
        detector.setProcessor(object : Detector.Processor<Barcode> {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            override fun receiveDetections(p0: Detector.Detections<Barcode>?) {
                val barcodes = p0?.detectedItems
                if (barcodes!!.size() > 0) {
                    builder.setMessage("barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue)
                    builder.setOnCancelListener{
                        val intent = Intent(this@FirstQrcodeActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("First_Qrcode",barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                    taskHandler.post(runnable)
                }
            }
        })
```

Main code in Second QRcode Activity , passing values to MainActivity:

```
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        svBarcode = findViewById(R.id.sv_Secondbarcode)
        detector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS).build()
        detector.setProcessor(object : Detector.Processor<Barcode> {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            override fun receiveDetections(p0: Detector.Detections<Barcode>?) {
                val barcodes = p0?.detectedItems
                if (barcodes!!.size() > 0) {
                    builder.setMessage("barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue)
                    builder.setOnCancelListener{
                        val intent = Intent(this@SecondQrcodeActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("Second_Qrcode",barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                    taskHandler.post(runnable)
                }
            }
        })
```

With these function I can successfully scan QR code and get value , but I can't put both value in both textview by two steps.

Once I click another button to scan second QR code and scan successfully, first value in my Textview will become Null. Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start MainActivity then it's every variable will reinitiate i.e. will become null
You have 2 solutions,

1. Save your values in SharedPreferences so that older value will not get 
   refer below tutorial for details
   https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-sharedpreferences-example/
2. use onActivity Result which will return back value from the second activity

In order to start an activity which should return result to the calling activity, you should do something like below. You should pass the requestcode as shown below in order to identify that you got the result from the activity you started.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(“YourFullyQualifiedClassName”),requestCode);
```

In the activity you can make use of `setData()` to return result.

```
Intent data = new Intent();
String text = "Result to be returned...."
//---set the data to pass back---
data.setData(Uri.parse(text));
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
//---close the activity---
finish();
```

So then again in the first activity you write the below code in onActivityResult()

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == request_Code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String returnedResult = data.getData().toString();
            // OR
            // String returnedResult = data.getDataString();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT based on your comment:**
If you want to return three strings, then follow this by making use of key/value pairs with intent instead of using Uri.

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("streetkey","streetname");
data.putExtra("citykey","cityname");
data.putExtra("homekey","homename");
setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
finish();
```

Get them in **onActivityResult** like below:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == request_Code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String street = data.getStringExtra("streetkey");
            String city = data.getStringExtra("citykey");
            String home = data.getStringExtra("homekey");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Saving it in SharedPreferences is bad practice because it is ment for different things, you should use onActivityResult()

Answer (score 0):

First when starting `ScannerActivity` from `MainActivity`, start it with  `startActivityForResult()`.

When returning result from `ScannerActivity`  replace `startActivity()` with `setResult()`.

And then listen results not `onStart()`, but `onActivityResult()` in `MainActivity`

Here is [Documentation for this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)